Can specific class types be altered without copying a class in C++?
I am trying to have a class in c++ that has variables of lets say an int and a function I will call foo in a derived class, and then change it so that all int's are now double's. This is an example:
template<bool int_mode>
class BaseT {
    public:
        using variable = std::conditional_t<int_mode, int, double>;
        BaseT() = default;
        virtual variable foo(variable var) {return 0;}
};


using Base = BaseT<true>;
using BaseDouble = BaseT<false>;

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        variable a, b, c;
        Derived()
            :a(10), b(20), c(30)
        {}

        variable foo(variable var) override {
            return var * a * b * c;
        }
};

double runDerivedDouble(Derived& cls){
    //in here I want to convert Derived to a version where the "variable"
    //types are all floats instead of ints, and then run foo
}


Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to have a macro that makes a separate class where the contents of foo are the same from the Derived class, but that the type variable is just changed and a separate class is generated for me.
For example, if I did made a class doing this and called it DerivedDouble this is what it would look like. However, my goal is that I wouldn't have to make this class. I would want a way to use a macro or something similar to generate this and what foo would output from the DerivedDouble class below. I am really just wondering if this is possible, and in a way such that I do not have to add a template to Derived? I am basically wondering if I can make a version of a class where the template on the base class can be changed?
class DerivedDouble : public BaseDouble{
    public:
        variable a, b, c;
        Derived()
            :a(10), b(20), c(30)
        {}

        variable foo(variable var) override {
            return var * a * b * c;
        }
};


Why not just make Derived a template?

"is possible to have a macro" - certainly, but Alan is on to a better pratice above.

Why not make the Base a template, based on type rather than an integral value?

In general I would say mixing templates (static polymorphism) and inheritance (dynamic polymorphism) is a desing smell (it could be right, but it should not be first choice).  Also the indirection from mode to int/double might kind of be surprising to the user of your code. It either needs to be documented or figured out by the user, which adds coginitive load. Keep it simple is doubly true for interfaces.

everything you can write as code can be hidden behind a macro, but why would you? It seems to be common to expect macros to do "magic". Also not correct, but much closer to the truth is that macros are merely a way to generate code. Code that you could write yourself. Hence whenever you wonder how something can be done, you can forget about macros until you know what code you would generate
